# how is Softlayer location defined when working with SoftLayer API?

Tags: python, api, location, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working on a Python script (sample code place_order_several_vms_vlan.py at https://softlayer.github.io/python/) that uses SoftLayer API. One attribute to set is "location". How is the location attribute is defined for SoftLayer in this context?

So far, I can only use "AMSTERDAM". Anything else, such as DAL05, failed.

Appreciate if someone can provide a list of locations that can be used in this context when working with SoftLayer API.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you use another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location is where your vm will be provisioned, and the python script example you are using is to place a new vm order in the AMSTERDAM location.

To get all the locations available to provision your vm use this rest api.

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters/

You have to keep in mind that the item prices are different for each location.

To get the item prices and their locations you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations]]
```

The response e.g will be like this:

```
{
        "currentPriceFlag": null,
        "hourlyRecurringFee": ".018",
        "id": 112475,
        "itemId": 857,
        "laborFee": "0",
        "locationGroupId": 503,
        "onSaleFlag": null,
        "oneTimeFee": "0",
        "quantity": null,
        "recurringFee": "11.21",
        "setupFee": "0",
        "sort": 0,
        "tierMinimumThreshold": null,
        "item": {
            "capacity": "1",
            "description": "1 x 2.0 GHz or higher Core",
            "id": 857,
            "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
            "keyName": "GUEST_CORE_1",
            "softwareDescriptionId": null,
            "units": "CORE",
            "upgradeItemId": null
        },
        "pricingLocationGroup": {
            "description": "Location Group 2",
            "id": 503,
            "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
            "name": "Location Group 2",
            "securityLevelId": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": 449610,
                    "longName": "Montreal 1",
                    "name": "mon01",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 449618,
                    "longName": "Montreal 2",
                    "name": "mon02",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 448994,
                    "longName": "Toronto 1",
                    "name": "tor01",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 350993,
                    "longName": "Toronto 2",
                    "name": "tor02",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 221894,
                    "longName": "Amsterdam 2",
                    "name": "ams02",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 265592,
                    "longName": "Amsterdam 1",
                    "name": "ams01",
                    "statusId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 814994,
                    "longName": "Amsterdam 3",
                    "name": "ams03",
                    "statusId": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

e.g. for the item "1 x 2.0 GHz or higher Core", the item price id will be "id": 112475, and you will see the locations available for this item.

If you do not find locations for a item is because the item price is standard, it means that all locations are available for this item.

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices/

Comment: Thank you @F.Ojeda. While running API getDatacenters, for data center in Amsterdam, it only returned {  
    'id':265592,
    'longName':'Amsterdam 1',
    'name':'ams01',
    'statusId':2
 },
 {  
    'id':814994,
    'longName':'Amsterdam 3',
    'name':'ams03',
    'statusId':2
 },

Comment: Nothing matches "AMSTERDAM". Note, the original sample script only works when location="AMSTERDAM" is defined. Nothing else works. I try to find out what other values that I can use in my script

Comment: Now, I understand your 2nd point - not all price package is available in all data center. Thank you. Also, when the data center ID is assigned to location, it works. But, it appears that I can assign a string such as "AMSTERDAM" to the location. What is "AMSTERDAM" in SL? Is it one of attributes?

Comment: The python script example is using Amsterdam 1 location, you can verify it with the location id in the request response searching that id in the datacenter request. There are just two Amsterdam location the same that the control portal Amsterdam 1 and Amsterdam 3.

Comment: You can assign a string to the location, in this case when you add just Amsterdam it is Amsterdam 1, but if you want to add Amsterdam 3 you have to add like Amstedam03. It is the same for the rest of the locations.